# Failed database migration left database in inconsistent state migrations failing

Tags: entity-framework, database-migration

I have the following 3 models which during some changes have left me with an inconsistent database state as I am unable to drop constraints on the table due to the deletion of a failed migration and the rollback to a previous version.

```
public class Bill
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int BillID { get; set; }

        ..........

        public int? LandlordID { get; set; }
        public virtual Landlord Landlord { get; set; }

        public int? LandlordBillID { get; set; }
        public virtual LandlordBill LandlordBill { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Meter> Meters { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Lift> Lifts { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Refund> Refunds { get; set; }
    }

public class HalfHourlyBill
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int BillID { get; set; }

        ...........

        public int? LandlordID { get; set; }
        public virtual Landlord Landlord { get; set; }

        public int? LandlordBillID { get; set; }
        public virtual LandlordBill LandlordBill { get; set; }

    }

 public class LandlordBill
    {
        [Key]
        public int LandlordBillID { get; set; }

        .........

        public virtual ICollection<Bill> Bills { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<HalfHourlyBill> HalfHourlyBills { get; set; }

        public int? LandlordID { get; set; }
        public virtual Landlord Landlord { get; set; }
    }
```

I am unsure as to how I can get back my code to be in the same state as my database as the last changes have messed this up and my migration code shown below just fails:

```
public override void Up()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Lift", "LandlordBill_LandlordBillID", "dbo.LandlordBill");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Meter", "LandlordBill_LandlordBillID", "dbo.LandlordBill");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Refund", "LandlordBill_LandlordBillID", "dbo.LandlordBill");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Bill", "LandlordID", "dbo.Landlord");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", "LandlordID", "dbo.Landlord");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Bill", "LandlordBillID", "dbo.LandlordBill");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", "LandlordBillID", "dbo.LandlordBill");
            DropIndex("dbo.Bill", new[] { "LandlordID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Bill", new[] { "LandlordBillID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Lift", new[] { "LandlordBill_LandlordBillID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Meter", new[] { "LandlordBill_LandlordBillID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Refund", new[] { "LandlordBill_LandlordBillID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", new[] { "LandlordID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", new[] { "LandlordBillID" });
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.LandlordBill");
            AddColumn("dbo.Bill", "Landlord_LandlordID", c => c.Guid());
            AddColumn("dbo.LandlordBill", "LandlordID", c => c.Int());
            AddColumn("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", "Landlord_LandlordID", c => c.Guid());
            AlterColumn("dbo.Bill", "LandlordID", c => c.Int());
            AlterColumn("dbo.Bill", "LandlordBillID", c => c.Int());
            AlterColumn("dbo.LandlordBill", "LandlordBillID", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
            AlterColumn("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", "LandlordID", c => c.Int());
            AlterColumn("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", "LandlordBillID", c => c.Int());
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.LandlordBill", "LandlordBillID");
            CreateIndex("dbo.Bill", "LandlordBillID");
            CreateIndex("dbo.Bill", "Landlord_LandlordID");
            CreateIndex("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", "LandlordBillID");
            CreateIndex("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", "Landlord_LandlordID");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Bill", "Landlord_LandlordID", "dbo.Landlord", "LandlordID");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", "Landlord_LandlordID", "dbo.Landlord", "LandlordID");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Bill", "LandlordBillID", "dbo.LandlordBill", "LandlordBillID");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", "LandlordBillID", "dbo.LandlordBill", "LandlordBillID");
            DropColumn("dbo.Lift", "LandlordBill_LandlordBillID");
            DropColumn("dbo.Meter", "LandlordBill_LandlordBillID");
            DropColumn("dbo.Refund", "LandlordBill_LandlordBillID");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.Refund", "LandlordBill_LandlordBillID", c => c.Guid());
            AddColumn("dbo.Meter", "LandlordBill_LandlordBillID", c => c.Guid());
            AddColumn("dbo.Lift", "LandlordBill_LandlordBillID", c => c.Guid());
            DropForeignKey("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", "LandlordBillID", "dbo.LandlordBill");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Bill", "LandlordBillID", "dbo.LandlordBill");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", "Landlord_LandlordID", "dbo.Landlord");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Bill", "Landlord_LandlordID", "dbo.Landlord");
            DropIndex("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", new[] { "Landlord_LandlordID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", new[] { "LandlordBillID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Bill", new[] { "Landlord_LandlordID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Bill", new[] { "LandlordBillID" });
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.LandlordBill");
            AlterColumn("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", "LandlordBillID", c => c.Guid());
            AlterColumn("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", "LandlordID", c => c.Guid());
            AlterColumn("dbo.LandlordBill", "LandlordBillID", c => c.Guid(nullable: false));
            AlterColumn("dbo.Bill", "LandlordBillID", c => c.Guid());
            AlterColumn("dbo.Bill", "LandlordID", c => c.Guid());
            DropColumn("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", "Landlord_LandlordID");
            DropColumn("dbo.LandlordBill", "LandlordID");
            DropColumn("dbo.Bill", "Landlord_LandlordID");
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.LandlordBill", "LandlordBillID");
            CreateIndex("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", "LandlordBillID");
            CreateIndex("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", "LandlordID");
            CreateIndex("dbo.Refund", "LandlordBill_LandlordBillID");
            CreateIndex("dbo.Meter", "LandlordBill_LandlordBillID");
            CreateIndex("dbo.Lift", "LandlordBill_LandlordBillID");
            CreateIndex("dbo.Bill", "LandlordBillID");
            CreateIndex("dbo.Bill", "LandlordID");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", "LandlordBillID", "dbo.LandlordBill", "LandlordBillID");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Bill", "LandlordBillID", "dbo.LandlordBill", "LandlordBillID");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.HalfHourlyBill", "LandlordID", "dbo.Landlord", "LandlordID");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Bill", "LandlordID", "dbo.Landlord", "LandlordID");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Refund", "LandlordBill_LandlordBillID", "dbo.LandlordBill", "LandlordBillID");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Meter", "LandlordBill_LandlordBillID", "dbo.LandlordBill", "LandlordBillID");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Lift", "LandlordBill_LandlordBillID", "dbo.LandlordBill", "LandlordBillID");
        }
```

The error that I am getting during the update of the migration is The constraint 'PK_dbo.LandlordBill' is being referenced by table 'HalfHourlyBill', foreign key constraint 'FK_dbo.HalfHourlyBill_dbo.LandlordBill_LandlordBillID'.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`I had a similar mess. Sometimes you can comment out commands that don't need to be run or rearrange the commands, but here is what I would do:

1) Generate a script for that migration

```
update-database -Script
```

2) That should show you the commands that will be run. Paste that script into SQL Management Studio and step through them to see what has been applied, and what hasn't.

3) The last command will update the __MigrationHistory to reflect the applied migration. You can run it, or you can just comment out the migration Up() code and do update-database.

If you trust things are in sync you could just comment out the Up() code and apply it or you can create a no-code migration to syncronize your database and code models:

`add-migration resyncModels -IgnoreChanges`.

Comment: Migrations are supposed to erradicate things like this how frustrating literally just ruined my day and I dont know where to go from here despite your suggestions