# Entity Framework code-first migration: revert migration not working using down() method

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have successfully add new column in table using `Add-Migration AddMobileNo` using Entity Framework code-first approach.

```
[Table("Student")]
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Add new column using "Add-Migration AddMobileNo"
    public string MobileNo { get; set; } 
}

public partial class AddMobileNo : DbMigration
{
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.Student", "MobileNo", c => c.String());
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("dbo.Student", "MobileNo");
        }
}
```

Now I am trying to revert a migration using this command for calling `down()` method:

```
update-database -TargetMigration: "AddMobileNo"
```

but it's not working for me and showing this message in PMC (Package Manager Console):

> Target database is already at version AddMobileNo

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I presume you checked your `MigrationHistory` table? Just thinking if this answer would help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609179/failed-database-migration-left-database-in-inconsistent-state-migrations-failing#35609870 9/?

Comment: The command you used means: "go back to the "AddMobileNo" migration" - but your database **already is** at that migration. If you want to undo this migration - you need to go back to the **previous** migration `-update-database -TargetMigration: "The-One-Just-Before-AddMobileNo"` ....

Comment: It's working for me.
Thank you so much @marc_s.